# No configuration found in the configured sources. Error while running logstash.conf file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

*I am trying to get Springboot logs via ELK stack and view them in Kibana. I can able to run `kibana.bat, elasticsearch.bat` files without any issues*

while I am trying to run `"logstash -f logstash.conf"` getting the below stack trace.

```
D:\ELK\logstash-7.13.2\bin>logstash -f logstash.conf
"Using bundled JDK: ""
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Sending Logstash logs to D:/ELK/logstash-7.13.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-06-27T22:31:46,792][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: D:\ELK\logstash-7.13.2\config\log4j2.properties
[2021-06-27T22:31:46,806][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.13.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.16.0 (2.5.7) 2021-03-03 f82228dc32 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.11+9 on 11.0.11+9 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-06-27T22:31:46,961][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-06-27T22:31:47,858][INFO ][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] No config files found in path {:path=>"D:/ELK/logstash-7.13.2/bin/logstash.conf"}
[2021-06-27T22:31:47,865][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] No configuration found in the configured sources.
[2021-06-27T22:31:48,043][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-06-27T22:31:53,222][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-06-27T22:31:53,230][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.16.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.16.0.jar:?]
        at D_3a_.ELK.logstash_minus_7_dot_13_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(D:\ELK\logstash-7.13.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]
```

Below is logstash.conf file

**logstash.conf**

```
input { 
  
  file{
    path=>"C:/Users/jagan/OneDrive/Desktop/logs/elk-stack.log"
    start_position=> "beginning"
  }

 }
output {
  
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  
}
```

**Location of logstash.conf file:**
`D:\ELK\logstash-7.13.2\bin`

**Location of log file:**
`C:\Users\jagan\OneDrive\Desktop\logs\elk-stack.log`

**Can some please help me with why I am getting this error, googled many journals that didn't get any resolution? I can confirm that all paths provided were correct.**
*(Similar questions in Stackoverflow were not answered properly please don't suggest other answers. Please let me know for any other details required)*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message "No config files found in path" indicate that after the [loader](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/a31a7a47360324ce838bda193afea3f791c1b46e/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/source/local.rb#L103) had finished reading the files in path.config it did not have a configuration. That could mean the file does not exist, or it is empty, or the user running logstash does not have permission to read it.